# Leaflet Routing Machine: how to dinamically change router settings?

Tags: leaflet, routing

I'm using Leaflet Routing Machine in a litte Leaflet + Javascript map.

I'm using Graphhopper as router in this way ....

```
var control = L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
    L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
    L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
  ],
  routeWhileDragging: true,
  geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
  router: L.Routing.graphHopper('a585904f-5193-4605-bc3c-870c4f472177' , {
    urlParameters: {
        vehicle: 'car'
    }
  })
}).addTo(map);
```

..... and all works fine

Now in my map I'd like to put give the opportunity to select, using a couple of buttons, the router "vehicle type", so if the user select "foot", I'd like to change the  route vehicle parameter setting to 'foot' value.

How may I set this value? Something like

```
 control.Router.?????? = 'foot'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the vehicle type, you would use:

```
control.getRouter().options.urlParameters.vehicle = 'foot';
```

However, the router does not automatically recalculate the route when you change the parameters, so to get the foot directions to show up, you will need to request it again:

```
control.route();
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer Code, change vehicle with profile:

```
control.getRouter().options.urlParameters.profile= 'foot';
control.route();
```